# C# ThreadStart with void method parametrized with Func

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to start a new thread like this

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public void DoThings(Func<object,string,string,bool> handler)
    {
        //...doing some stuff
        object param1 = ...
        string param2 = ...
        string param3 = ...

        if (somecondition)
            handler(param1, param2, param3);
        //...do other stuff 
    }
}

public class MyClass2
{
    public bool DoParticularThing(object p1, string p2, string p3)
    {
        //..do stuff
    }

    public MyClass2()
    {
        var myclass1Instance = new MyClass1();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myclass1Instance.DoThings(DoParticularThing))); //here comes my error
    }


}
```

Unfortunately I keep on getting the "Method name expected" error. I went through a bunch of posts and I don't understand what's the issue.

Comment: Please be precise, what error do you get where?

Comment: There is a comment in the las line where I say what error I get. It's on the myclass1Instance.DoThings(DoParticularThing) line part.

Comment: You can start with a lambda function: `var t = new Thread(() => myclass1Instance.DoThings(DoParticularThing));`

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to create your own Thread? You have ThreadPool and you have Task ...

Comment: That code is going to require 3 arguments.  Where do their values come from?  Address that first and you'll have a much easier time writing the correct lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

it happens because of you are creating a ThreadStart with a void function which requires a delegate type, so you should simply do thing like:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>myclass1Instance.DoThings(DoParticularThing)));
```

using a lambda syntax,
also it worth mentioning  that Thread class is pretty old and you better use Tasks which are way more nicer and supports things like cancelation tokens and bunch of other cool stuffs.
the syntax is:

```
Task<bool>.Run(()=>{
 //..do stuff,the logic of your DoParticularThing function
});
```